# Package 'libmyodbc' has no installation candidate

Tags: 18.04, package-management, mysql

trying to install libmyodbc package. but got error:

```
Package 'libmyodbc' has no installation candidate
```

(need it for MySQL ODBC Driver)

was trying already:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

and nothing changed. 
Looking for solutions. Thanks.

Comment: That package does not exist in official Ubuntu repositories. To know how you can obtain it, ask whoever told you to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for advice. I found a solution on:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#Ubuntu 14.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/14.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Ubuntu 16.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Ubuntu 18.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Ubuntu 18.10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Comment: MySQL is not the same RDBMS as MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server), please fix your question.